# SharePoint 2010 Workflow (greater than or equal to)

Tags: 2010, designer-workflow

Just wondering if the below is possible in SharePoint designer or another way that I cant figure out.

I want to change the status of a field say `REQStatus` so my rules would be:

```
If Qreq is = 0 set REQStatus to "Not Received"

or/then If Qreq is > 0 and < Oreq set REQStatus to "Partially Received"

or/then If Qreq is > or equal to Oreq set REQStatus to "Fully Received"
```

I can get the first statement to work, along with the last by using the wait option but for the `or/then If Qreq is > 0 and < Oreq set REQStatus to "Partially Received` statement I get an error when trying to change it to greater than.

Comment: What do you think about the Calculated column instead of workflow? You can configure it easily to set value of column based on the other one. In case you don't like it or it don't match your require, would you like to describe your scenario in details. I don't understand about the part "or/then". p/s: sorry for writing an answer, but my score is not enough to comment. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fault is in your logic, you can't do a compound evalution like that. You'd need to do it like:

```
If Qreq is = 0 set REQStatus to "Not Received"
else If Qreq is > 0 and Qreq < Oreq set REQStatus to "Partially Received"
else If Qreq is > or equal to Oreq set REQStatus to "Fully Received"
```

[image]

Comment: Eric,

How would I get the "and"/"or" part to work on a workflow using SharePoint designer? when I type and after "else if Qreq is > 0 it finishes the line... with what I'm trying to do is it only possible in a calculated SharePoint column?

Comment: You simply add an additional evaluation like you did in the previous condition. You can toggle is as an and or an or.

Comment: I added an rough example, i just threw it together quickly on an announcements list so the operators aren't right, but it shows what I mean.

Comment: I'm still a bit confused as i'm pretty new to sharepoint, maybe seeing what I have so far would help?
http://postimg.org/image/5efl0kdqr/

I see your example which looks great but i'm confused as to where I can find the "and" to add it in front of the value see other screenshot when I try to type it...
http://postimg.org/image/4y04453jx/

Comment: Eric, I got it, I had to add the same Condition inside the first box, sorry and thanks for helping!